# Java Program causes infinite loop

Tags: java, class, interface

This is my Java code. I have created one interface `abc` with two classes. class a1 implements interface `abc`. Class b1 uses the interface function `display` to show some data.

**class `a1` runs in an infinite loop.**

```
interface abc
{
  display(String s);
}

class a1 implments abc
{
   a1(b1 obj)
  {
  }
    public void display(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class b1
{
    abc abc1;
    private xyz x;
    b1(xyz xyz1)    //xyz is interface
    {
           this.x = xyz1; 
    }
    public void show()
    {
          abc1 = new a1(new b1(this.x));   //  here is problm.. this statement cause infinite loop.
          String str = "Hello"; 
          abc1.display(str);
    }
}
```

This program causes infinite loop of class `a1`.
Please find the problem and help me solve.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: This program has no errors. but cause infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, it has errors. You misspelled "implements" and forgot the `void` at the start of the declaration of  `display`

Comment: Could you also give your main Class? It seems you are creating a object of interface which is not possible

Comment: you have circular dependeincies there.... does a1 really needs a b1 object?

Comment: yes @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Answer (score 0):

It has no infinite loop.
I have created a main and called b1.show and it is running successfully.

```
interface abc
{
   void display(String s);
}

class a1 implements abc
{  
   a1(b1 obj)
  {
}
  public void display(String s)
  {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}

class b1
{
   abc abc1;
   private xyz x;
   b1(xyz xyz1)    //xyz is interface
   {
       this.x = xyz1; 
}
    public void show()
    {
        abc1 = new a1(new b1(this.x));   //  here is problm.. this statement cause infinite loop.
        String str = "Hello"; 
        abc1.display(str);
   }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      xyz xyz1 = null;
        b1 objb1=new b1(xyz1); 
      objb1.show();
      System.out.println("out of all classes..");
  }

}

interface xyz{

}
```